# Error using Tax4Fun2 (R package) with runRefBlast() function

Tags: r

I am trying the next code in R (with Tax4Fun2-R package), but always I get the next ERROR when I put  runRefBlast() function:

(base) juanm@juanm-Compaq-CQ58-Notebook-PC:~$ export PATH=$PATH:/media/juanm/d631a66f-81da-495d-8136-67bc214cb51d2/Tax4Fun2/R/Tax4Fun2_ReferenceData_v2/blast_bin/bin/

(base) juanm@juanm-Compaq-CQ58-Notebook-PC:~$ R

PATH = "media/juanm/d631a66f-81da-495d-8136-67bc214cb51d2/Tax4Fun2/R/Tax4Fun2_ReferenceData_v2/blast_bin/bin/"

runRefBlast(path_to_otus = "media/juanm/d631a66f-81da-495d-8136-67bc214cb51d2/Tax4Fun2/R/fasta",
path_to_reference_data = PATH,
path_to_temp_folder = "media/juanm/d631a66f-81da-495d-8136-67bc214cb51d2/Tax4Fun2/R/Ref100NR",
database_mode = "Ref100NR",
use_force = T, num_threads = 4)

chmod: can't access to '/home/juanm/d631a66f-81da-495d-8136-67bc214cb51d2/Tax4Fun2/R/Tax4Fun2_ReferenceData_v2//blast_bin/bin/blastn': It doesn't exist the file or directory
sh: 1: /home/juanm/d631a66f-81da-495d-8136-67bc214cb51d2/Tax4Fun2/R/Tax4Fun2_ReferenceData_v2//blast_bin/bin/blastn: not found
**Error in system(command = paste(blast_bin, "-help"), intern = T) :
error in running command**

> 

But all these folders and files have root permissions.And also I have tried it using nautilus, but the error is the same.

Please, could you help me to solve this error if you know how?.

I use Ubuntu 16.0 and R 4.1.1.

Thank you very much

Comment: Just a wild guess, but start your session with `sudo R`, toss in your password for the session and you'll likely have access to those files and folders.

Comment: Thank you Chris.When I start my session with sudo R, it loads and opens R-3.2.3 (my first seesion was with R-4.1.1) and this is the message: Error: Invalid restore file magic number (file may be corrupted) -- no data reloaded.And : Warning message:
file ‘.RData’ has magic number 'RDX3'
  Use of save versions prior to 2 is deprecated 
During the initialization - Warning message:unable to restore saved data in .RData

Comment: From your chmod error above: `ReferenceData_v2//blast_bin/bin/`, note the `//` which may? be due to some paste?... Do you have [two or several versions of R installed](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486138-Changing-R-versions-for-the-RStudio-Desktop-IDE)? So, in the presence of `//`, sudo not needed, just teasing out how one `/` became `//` in the call to the fasta data...And is it a compaq convention to have hash-like file paths, seems like that could get very annoying.

Comment: Chris, How could I get the version of R-4.1.1 (instead of R-3.2.3) to open from root (#) in my Ubuntu Terminal?.Thank you.

Comment: In a terminal, what does `which R` output? Mine, `which R
/usr/local/bin/R`, then `/usr/local/bin/R --version` tells you which is found. I have only one version working at a time.  In the presence of 2 or more, `which -a R`, will return all in Path. Then open a terminal and start R with the executable pointing to R-4.1.1 using the full path.

Comment: Thank you very much,Chris I already did it for R-4.1.1.

Comment: And has this helped with the `/` versus `//` difference in file paths, or just allowed you to control which version of R is called when you start a terminal session?